# Checking whether method is defined in *this* class

Tags: ruby

I have the following piece of code. It is actually three separate scripts except I combined it together. The `Main` class is something  the two `Test` classes inherit. They may define an `out` method, which will do whatever the devs want. This is meant to be a plugin-style sort of design so that people can define their own `out` methods in their own classes, and then when my main program picks up one of those custom classes I can just say

`some_test.run`

And if they decided to implement an `out` method that will be executed.

Is there a better way to implement the `run` method so that I don't need to explicitly write `self.class.method_defined?`? The object could be any `Test` object and I don't want them to have to overwrite the `run` method to put their own class name in front of the `method_defined?` call.

```
class Main
  def run
    send(:out) if self.class.method_defined?(:out)
  end
end

class TestA < Main

  def out
    p "Test A here"
  end
end

class TestB < Main

  def out
    p "Test B here"
  end
end

a = TestA.new
a.run
# will execute a's out method

b = TestB.new
b.run
# will execute b's out method
```

Comment: what's the problem with `self.class`?

Comment: Some people break rules and override the `class` method and then will complain to me that it doesn't work, so I figured I'll see if there's a different way to approach it that doesn't require me to retrieve the class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just provide an empty `out` method in the parent class and allow subclasses to override it, just normal OO:

```
class Main
  def run
    out
  end

  def out
    #out will now always be defined
  end
end
```

You could also just use `defined?`:

```
class Main
  def run
    out if defined? out
  end
end
```

Note the argument to `defined` is `out`, not the symbol `:out`.

Or, more idiomatically, you can use `respond_to?`:

```
class Main
  def run
    out if respond_to? :out
  end
end
```

Comment: Never seen `defined?` keyword used for that, it is usually `respond_to?` method, e.g. `something.respond_to?(:out)`.

Comment: @SemyonPerepelitsa you’re right. I think I saw `method_defined?` in the question and just thought of `defined?`. `respond_to?` is certainly more idiomatic, I’ll add it to my answer.